# b-toast notification is overlay in modal in bootstrap-vue in VUEJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toast, bootstrap-vue, vue-toasted

[This is picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXyBv.png)

I'm using $bvToast.toast() for using toast notification.
**This is some line of code**

```
 this.$bvToast.toast('Hit enter to submit\n Click outside to cancel', {
        title: 'Variant info',
        autoHideDelay: 2000,
        appendToast: true,
        solid: true,
        toastClass: {zIndex:9999999}
      })
```

I think it's kind of having problem with z-index but I do not how to override z-index for b-toast? I saw some property `toastClass`, I set `toastClass:{zIndex:9999}`, but it still not work.

**Edit 1**:I just add `toastIndex` in `data` and use it like in -pic 2-. Is that right? I'm not familiar with syntax?
[full pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYJzN.png)
[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1mTf.png)

[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YquMX.png)

Comment: `toastClass` is supposed to be a CSS class, put the `z-index` in your CSS and pass the class. [Reference](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/toast).

Comment: Could you show me how to implement it??

Comment: I have no way of knowing what your project looks like, but you just need to add a CSS class that sets the `z-index` in your CSS and then change `toastClass` to be a string with that class.

Comment: Actually, this seems to be the expected behavior, the demo on [Bootstrap Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/toast) has the same issue. It looks more like the transparency of the toast is causing the issue. See [here](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/toast#transparency) to modify the transparency.

Comment: I just edit the post, pls check it if u have time, I think it's not caused by transparency of the toast cuz I set solid property = true.